# WIFi issue ubuntu13.10

Tags: wireless

Asus X55C wifi not enabling. The wifi is disabled by hardware switch. Switch on laptop is un-responsive. Wireless is enabled in the Bios as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, be certain you have a driver associated with the hardware; if so, it should create a wireless interface wlan0 or eth1. Confirm:

```
iwconfig
```

Temporarily unload the module acer-wmi:

```
sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

Is your wireless working now? If so, and if there are no other unexpected side-effects, blacklist acer-wmi:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist acer-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```